# RegEx replace <div foo> with <div data-foo>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, string

I'm currently learning how to use RegEx. I couldn't find a tutorial (or didnt know where to look) for replacing the result with the previous content.

I've managed to get the regex for extracting foo and bar

```
<div foo bar=""></div>
```

I want to obtain:

```
<div data-foo data-bar=""></div>
```

Here's how I'm trying to do it:

```
str = str.replace(/[^<div ][^/div]\w+/g, 'data-$1');
```

However, $1 doesnt get replaced by foo and bar.

Can someone help me? I'm stuck here!

Thank you very much!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Answer (score 0):

Try replaceing the regex to:

```
/([^<div ][^/div]\w+)/g
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#grouping-back-references